# A Linux Daemon and the STDIN/STDOUT

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am working on a linux daemon and having some issues with the stdin/stdout. Normally because of the nature of a daemon you do not have any stdin or stdout. However, I do have a function in my daemon that is called when the daemon runs for the first time to specify different parameters that are required for the daemon to run successfully. When this function is called the terminal becomes so sluggish that I have to launch a seperate shell and kill the daemon with top to get a responsive prompt back. Now I suspect that this has something to do with the forking process closing the stdin/stdout but I am not quite sure how I could work around this. If you guys could shed some light on the situation that would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

```
int main(argc, char *argv[]) {

/* setup signal handling */

/* check command line arguments */

pid_t pid, sid;

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(pid > 0){
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

sid = setsid();

if(sid < 0) {
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

umask(027);

/* set syslogging */

/* do some logic to determine wether we are running the daemon for the first time and if we are call the one time function which uses fgets() to recieve some input */

while(1) {

/* do required work */

}

/* do some clean up procedures and exit */

return 0;
}
```

You guys mention using a config file. This is is exactly what I do to store the parameters recieved via input. However I still initially need to get these from the user via the stdin. The logic for determining whether we are running for the first time is based off of the existence of the config file.

Comment: We have no idea without seeing some code. But it sounds like you're doing it wrong. Are you saying you want the daemon to be able to take stdin/stdout? You'll have to pipe them over a socket or something.

Comment: Yes Falmarri but only when that particular function is called which like I said is a one time thing. In my code I call this function after I fork(); a new process.

Comment: Your terminal is not really sluggish, your spawned subprocess inherited the same fd and is stealing your input (you now have multiple readers), and the result is undefined (race condition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You guys mention using a config file. This is is exactly what I do to store the parameters recieved via input. However I still initially need to get these from the user via the stdin. The logic for determining whether we are running for the first time is based off of the existence of the config file.

***Instead of*** reading stdin, have the user write the config file themselves; check for its existence *before* forking, and exit with an error if it doesn't.  Include a sample config file with the daemon, and document its format in your daemon's manpage.  You *do* have a manpage, yes?  Your config file *is* textual, yes?

Also, your daemonization logic is missing a key step. After forking, but before calling `setsid`, you need to close fds 0, 1, and 2 and reopen them to `/dev/null` (do *not* attempt to do this with `fclose` and `fopen`).  That should fix your sluggish terminal problem.

Comment: ouch rely on the user to write the config file? Also I did try doing any I/O before the forking process and I still get the same issue with the sluggish terminal.

Comment: Yes, absolutely rely on the user to write the config file.  That is the way this is done with Unix.  Re the sluggish terminal, see edit.

Comment: "Do *not* attempt to do this with `fclose` and `fopen`." Why so, and how *should* we attempt to do this?

Comment: You do it with the OS primitives, [`close`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) and [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open).  If you do it with `fclose` and `fopen`, the I/O buffers will get screwed up.

Answer (score 15):

Normally, the standard input of a daemon should be connected to `/dev/null`, so that if anything is read from standard input, you get an EOF immediately.  Normally, standard output should be connected to a file - either a log file or `/dev/null`.  The latter means all writes will succeed, but no information will be stored.  Similarly, standard error should be connected to `/dev/null` or to a log file.

All programs, including daemons, are entitled to assume that stdin, stdout and stderr are appropriately opened file streams.

It is usually appropriate for a daemon to control where its input comes from and outputs go to. There is seldom occasion for input to come from other than `/dev/null`.  If the code was written to survive without standard output or standard error (for example, it opens a standard log channel, or perhaps uses `syslog(3)`) then it may be appropriate to close stdout and stderr.  Otherwise, it is probably appropriate to redirect them to `/dev/null`, while still logging messages to a log file.  Alternatively, you can redirect both stdout and stderr to a log file - beware continuously growing log files.

Your sluggish-to-impossible response time might be because your program is not paying attention to EOF in a read loop somewhere.  It might be prompting for user input on /dev/null, and reading a response from /dev/null, and not getting a 'y' or 'n' back, it tries again, which chews up your system horribly.  Of course, the code is flawed in not handling EOF, and counting the number of times it gets an invalid response and stopping being silly after a reasonable number of attempts (16, 32, 64).  The program should shut up shop sanely and safely if it expects a meaningful input and continues not to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Your design is wrong.  Daemon processes should not take input via stdin or deliver output to stdout/stderr.  You'll close those descriptors as part of the daemonizing phase.  Daemons should take configuration parameters from the command line, a config file, or both.  If runtime-input is required you'll have to read a file, open a socket, etc., but the point of a daemon is that it should be able to run and do its thing without a user being present at the console.

Comment: Unless this is a daemon run by inetd... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your program detached, use [the shell](https://superuser.com/a/172476/297173): `(setsid <command> &)`. Do not `fork()` inside your program, which will [cause sysadmin nightmare](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).

[Don't use `syslog()`](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html) nor [redirect `stdout` or `stderr`](http://cloud9.hedgee.com./scribbles/daemon#logging).

Better yet, use a [daemon manager](http://blog.darknedgy.net/technology/2015/09/05/0/) such as daemon tools, runit, OpenRC and systemd, to daemonize your program for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a config file. Do not use STDIN or STDOUT with a daemon. Daemons are meant to run in the **background** with no user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using stdin/keyboard input to fire up the daemon (e.g. to get some magic passphrase you wouldn't want to store in a file) then handle all I/O *before* the `fork()`.

Comment: Well I thought of that and just tried it to confirm and I still get the same issue with the sluggish terminal. It is quite baffling to me.

Comment: You code snippet seems to suggest otherwise. Please share real code if you want to solve the issue.