# kill and restart the application from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to invoke the script from the c code, wherein the script file kills the application and restarts

```
/* testApp.c */
int main()
{
    int data;
    printf("Enter the data\n");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    
    /* Invoke the script file */
    system("script.sh");

}
```

and below is the script file

```
#!/bin/sh

pkill testApp

start-stop-daemon --start  --user root --name testApp --startas testApp -- --daemon
pidof testApp
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
    echo "Restart of testApp success!!" 
else
    echo "Restart of testApp failed!!"
    exit 1  
fi

exit 0
```

when the application is executed, it terminates the running process and restarts the application, but it is not waiting at scanf for user input, just continues to execute
why isn't the application waiting for user input, if invoked from script file

Comment: I don't get everything you want to do here, but if you are launching a daemon, won't the input stream (i.e. stdin) be decoupled from the terminal you are launching the daemon from ? just a thought. Here is a link to a question that answers that thought https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869860/a-linux-daemon-and-the-stdin-stdout

Comment: I am trying to just restart the testApp application from script

Comment: Sure, but again: if your app is running as a daemon, then it will likely not have an input stream, unless you specifically open one. So scanf() will scan nothing and likely return a I/O error.